# Unexpected int/Integer behavior when number starts by 0

Tags: java, integer, literals

I can't understand why this is not printing the expected value (400300) when I put extra zeros in front of the number:

```
System.out.println(new Integer(0400300)); // prints 131264
System.out.println(0400300); // prints 131264
```

If I put one or more zeros in front of the number, the expected value is not printed.

```
// JUnit test does not pass:
assertTrue(0400300 == 400300);  // returns false!?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `0` to the front made the number an `Octal literal`. So:

```
0400300 = 3 * 8 ^ 2 + 4 * 8 ^ 5 = 131264
```

See JLS for the [relevant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) sections. Quote:

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Comment: Is this a new Java 7 behavior? Or is something that exists in previous versions of Java?

Comment: It's ancient, I am not sure but I think this should have been there since day one. But with no concrete evidence (JLS 1.0) I really can't say for sure.

Comment: Hexa starts with 0x, binary with 0b (binary literals started in Java 7). But octal literals I can't find in documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: It's rather strange that that page mentions nothing about octal literals. Also the knowledge of binary literal is nice,

Comment: That's not documentation - it's a tutorial. You can read the link for JLS I gave in the answer and search for octal. Just edited answer too.

Comment: IMO a tutorial that shows hexa and binary literals should talk about octal literals.

Comment: Well that's a bug in the tutorial. I think there are quite a handful of them, so yo could just give them a feedback by clicking the link in the bottom. But JLS is the ultimate reference in any Java related matters.